# Array_push within foreach loop overwites earlier arrey values

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I'm trying to build a multidimentional array of matches found within a foreach loop. After one loop the array is correct but on the second loop, the earlier array values are overwritten. What is going on?

```
$matches = array();
foreach ($promotions as $promotion) {
   $matches = array();
   foreach ($saleitems as $saleitem) {
     if ($saleitem['PROMO_CODE'] == $promotion['SALES_CODE']) {
       $matches[] = array('ID'=>$saleitem['ID'], "LINENO"=>$saleitem['LINE'], "SAVING"=>"0", 'SALEINC'=>$saleitem['SALEINC']);
     }
   }
//other code with works out discount etc.
$linesarray[] = array("CODE"=>$promotion['CODE'], "LINES"=>$matches);
print_r($linesarray);
echo "<p>";
}
```

Outputs this:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [CODE] => 5 [LINES] => Array ( [0] => Array ([ID] => 51016 [LINENO] => 4 [SAVING] => 5 [SALEINC] => 15.00 ) [1] => Array ([ID] => 51013 [LINENO] => 3 [SAVING] => 5 [SALEINC] => 15.00 ) ) ) )

Array ( [0] => Array ( [CODE] => 5 [LINES] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [ID] => 51016 [LINENO] => 4 [SAVING] => 5 [SALEINC] => 15.00 ) [1] => Array ([ID] => 43930 [LINENO] => 2 [SAVING] => 0 [SALEINC] => 16.00 ) ) ) [1] => Array ( [CODE] => 7 [LINES] => Array ( [0] => Array ([ID] => 43914 [LINENO] => 1 [SAVING] => 6 [SALEINC] => 16.00 ) [1] => Array ([ID] => 43930 [LINENO] => 2 [SAVING] => 6 [SALEINC] => 16.00 ) ) ) )
```

As you can see LINENO 3 has been replaced the first array on second loop. Why?

Comment: Every time you start that outer loop, you reset $matches to an empty array.  Try taking that out.

Answer (score 1):

The `$matches = array();` inside the loop will reinitialize the array. The `$matches = array();` before the loop is fine.

Answer (score 0):

```
   $matches[] = array('ID'=>$saleitem['ID'], "LINENO"=>$saleitem['LINE'], "SAVING"=>"0", 'SALEINC'=>$saleitem['SALEINC']);
```

I see you fixed `"SAVING"=>"0"`  but your outputs have other result  `[SAVING] => 5`  Did you run your code again?

You should give us `$promotions` and `$saleitems` array.